# Issuing a single command from a cluster of servers?

Tags: bash, zookeeper, etcd

I have a cluster of servers that will be running a simple `ruok` command with fallover. The command will be something simple like `curl -X POST http://foo.com/status`. Due to the fact that I will have anywhere from 3 to 300 nodes in this pool, I want to make sure that this command is only emitted once every ten minutes. I ran into the issue that I cannot just add a crontab to my servers unless I want them all to emit every X minutes.

I started looking at using [HashiCorp Consul](https://www.consul.io/) as its fairly highly available and seemingly easier than `etcd` or `Zookeeper`. I do not know how to actually create something that will do this though.

I will be using this script on all servers

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json"    \
-X POST --data '{"status":"ruok"}' "https://foobar.com/status"
```

So how would I write Consul in order to run this once in a pool of nodes?

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/EvanKrall/cronsul)? I just searched Google now for "distributed cron using consul"...

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie that works great, please post as an answer so I can accept =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this](https://github.com/EvanKrall/cronsul).

Just Googled "distributed cron using consul".